# How to properly use pygame.event

Tags: python, pygame

For every simple program I write using pygame,
`pygame.event.get()` is empty, even if I use the keyboard or mouse.

What could be the reason?

For example, the code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
while True:
    pygame.event.get()
```

yields the following output:

```
[]
[]
...
[]
[]
```

Comment: I think it won't work unless you initialize a window, try `screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))` before your loop.

Comment: Without trying it, I agree with @user3557327. Seems like Pygame is necessarily only listening for events on a surface that it owns. Since it doesn't own a screen, it gets no events!

Answer (score 0):

I quote from [pygame's docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html):

> Pygame handles all its event messaging through an event queue. The routines in this module help you manage that event queue. **The input queue is heavily dependent on the pygame display module. If the display has not been initialized and a video mode not set, the event queue will not really work.**

So what @user3557327 states above is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing is that the pygame.event.get is a generator.
It will only works if you put it into a for in.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((530, 212));
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print event;
```